# Evaluting sin function using factorial series in C++

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I was trying to calculate the sin value of a user input using factorials (series)  but whenever I input any value  I get "-nan(ind)" as an output
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int N, i, j, fact = 1, sign = 1;
    float x, y = 0;
    cout << "Enter N (number of iterations),x (angle value in rad): ";
    cin >> N >> x;
    for (i = 1;i <= N;i++) {
        fact = 1;
        for (j = 1;j <= i;j++) {
            fact *= j;
        }
        y += sign * (pow(x, 2 * i - 1)) / fact;
        sign *= -1;
    }
    cout << "sin(" << x << ") = " << y << " the real value should be " << sin(x);
}
```

Comment: [I got](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wfCYbv6l4KpeB8KB) output `Enter N (number of iterations),x (angle value in rad): sin(0.5) = 0.442398 the real value should be 0.479426` for input `10 0.5`.

Comment: Not sure why you have a nested loop to calculate the factorial. Can't you just keep a running value for `fact` instead of resetting it to `1` every time?

Comment: Also note that `int` is used for factorial, so it will cause overflow if `N` is too large.

Comment: Where "too large" may be quite a bit smaller than you expect. For instance, on my system, `13!` is enough. On some systems, `N = 8` would be enough to cause problems.

Comment: The factorial of any value 13 or more will overflow a 32-bit `int`, causing undefined behaviour. If your compiler supports a 64-bit `int` (relatively rare) then overflow and undefined behaviour occurs for 20 or more. In any event, the terms in the Taylor's series for sin() are of the form `x^n/n!` (using `^` to mean "to power of") which, even for a moderately large `x`, involves calculating and dividing two large values. Look for alternative strategies, such as exploiting the relationship between consecutive terms in the series, to avoid explicitly calculating and dividing such large values